# How to Close a Form application after clicking a button on C#

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-3.0

I have created a Windows forms application using C#.

[image: This is my c sharp application picture]

I have used `this.close();` on a button to close a form.

Please tell me, is there other way to close the form?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're glad you're here. As written, your question is not likely to receive good answers. Keep in mind that a big part of our site is that answers aren't just for your benefit, but for the benefit of the next person who has a similar problem. Instead of including a temporary link to an image, paste the image directly into your question. Include the relevant code from the `click` event handler for your close button. Read up on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get an idea of what a well written question should look like.

Comment: i'm just asking about my problems. i don't know why people gave negative ratings.

Comment: Do you just want to know how many ways there are to close a form or is there something specific that's not working for you?

Comment: That's a perfectly acceptable way to close the Form...and if it's the instance passed to `Application.Run()` in `program.cs`, then the whole application will close as well (unless you have a non-background thread currently running).  Another way is to use [Application.Exit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx), but the form would then be closing as a side-effect of the whole app shutting down.  Are you having a specific problem with `this.Close();`?

Comment: Consider the explanation for a downvote: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Perhaps the downvoter is disappointed because s/he can't answer your question because you haven't included any code.

Comment: @mim It's because you haven't asked an answerable question.  Be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and what's going wrong.  **Include code samples**.

Answer (score 1):

try: this.Hide();
this.Show(newForm);

Answer (score -3):

You are not using the correct syntax. Try this...

```
this.hide()
```

Comment: this is not closing form application ... i thing this is hiding this.   `thisclose()` is  right